# Print hash on table html - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an instance variable `@report_antennas_control_access` with this data 
`[{:id_control_access=>1, :input=>"Antena 1"}, {:id_control_access=>1, :output=>"Antena 2"}, {:id_control_access=>1, :input=>"Antena 5"}, {:id_control_access=>2, :input=>"Antena 3"}, {:id_control_access=>2, :output=>"Antena 4"}]` and I want to print it in my .html table but in doing so I do it in a way that I do not want

I do it this way:

```
                  <tbody>
                    <% @report_antennas_control_access.each do | antennas | %>
                      <tr>
                        <% if control_access[:id_control_access] == antennas[:id_control_access] %>
                          <td><%= antennas[:input] %></td>
                          <td><%= antennas[:output] %></td>
                        <% end %>
                      </tr>
                    <% end %>
                  </tbody>
```

But he prints it to me in a way I do not want:

[image]

This is the way I need to print that data (example):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David already said, with your input, it will be really difficult to achieve what you need. Since it was fun, I fixed it, but I do believe that it should be fixed somewhere higher in your code (I hope you're using Ruby 2.5+, if not, let me know which version you are on).

```
def fix_my_data(data)
  data.group_by { |x| x[:id_control_access] }
      .transform_values do |v|
        v.map { |h| h.slice(:input, :output) }
         .group_by { |h| h.keys.first }.values.inject(:zip).map { |x,y| x.merge(y.to_h) }
      end
end
```

If you pass your array into this function, it will return this:

```
{1=>[{:input=>"Antena 1", :output=>"Antena 2"}, {:input=>"Antena 5"}],
 2=>[{:input=>"Antena 3", :output=>"Antena 4"}]}
```

Which should be really simple to generate HTML with, like so:

```
<tr>
  <% @data[control_access[:id_control_access]].each do |antenna| %>
    <td><%= antenna[:input] %></td>
    <td><%= antenna[:output] %></td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

I'm pretty sure `fix_my_data` can be written in a bit simpler way, but as I mentioned, it's a late place to be fixing the data.

Comment: Nice! Based on your solution I tried the following:    grouped = a.group_by {|e| e[:id_control_access]};
    grouped.transform_values {|arr| 
        arr.collect {|hash| hash.reject{|k,v| ![:input,:output].include?(k) } }.reduce(&:merge) 
    }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are iterating over each hash and trying to access data in either the hash before or after.  Take the first hash for example: `{:id_control_access=>1, :input=>"Antena 1"}`.  You call `antennas[:input]` on it, so it displays "Antena 1".  But then you call `antennas[:output]`, and there is no `output` key in the current hash, so it's returning `nil` and causing the corresponding table cell to be blank.

You should consider updating the structure of your hashes, if you can, so that they look like `{:id_control_access=>1, :input=>"Antena 1", :output=>"Antena 2"}`. It seems to me to make more logical sense, and would solve the problem with your table.